# What to use ? Bloc or Moor in Flutter

Tags: flutter

So, I am trying to create a project where I am supposed to Call Web API and store the data in my local storage. Which should still have even if the app is killed and then re-opened.

FYI, data will be large and I will require a significant amount of space in the mobile device.
i will be using firebase for login, the payment transaction and etc.

Comment: I believe that this is not the question to ask on stack overflow. Do your research and weight the results. And you are comparing a way to divide business logic (Bloc) with a wrapper of sqflite (Moor).

Answer (score 4):

this is my first answer, I hope to help you.

[**BloC**](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/whybloc) & [**Moor**](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/) are not synonyms, **BloC** is a reactive state management solution that allows you to better manage the interaction between logic and widgets in a reactive way. **Moor** is a layer between **sqlite** and your application, it allows you to deal with **sqlite** using dart code by reacting to database changes through **Stream**s and **Future**s

I think you do not need to choose one of the two, if your application is going to handle large amounts of data and will grow exponentially I recommend that you implement both as they complement each other, by designing a [**SOLID**](https://itnext.io/solid-principles-explanation-and-examples-715b975dcad4) structure.